# Express 500 Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pug, restify

I am trying to do simple update operation in mongodb. I have done it successfully using node.js, Express.js and Jade.js. Now I want to use restify.js in my existing application for rest api. but it is throwing "Express 500 Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters"

This is my index.jade (form part):

```
form( method="get", action="/employee/:id/edit")
  input(name="_id", type="hidden", value=employee._id.toHexString())
  input(name="com", type="hidden", value=''+employee.comment)
  input(name="titl", type="hidden", value=''+employee.title)
  input(name="nam", type="hidden", value=''+employee.name)
  input(id="edit", value="Edit", type="submit", class="btn btn-primary")
```

This is my employee_edit.jade:

```
form( method="post")
  span.label My comment type is :
  select(name='title')
    - for (var i=0; i<2; i++)
      if titl==arr2[i]
        option(value=arr2[i], selected='selected')
          =''+arr2[i]
      else
        option(value=arr2[i])
          =''+arr2[i]
  span.label My comment is for :
  select(name='name', selectedInex=3)
    - for (var i=0; i<22; i++)
      if nam==arr[i]
        option(value=arr[i], selected='selected')
          =''+arr[i]
      else
        option(value=arr[i])
          =''+arr[i]
  span.label Comment :
  textarea(rows='4', cols='50', name='comment', id='com')
    =''+com
  input(type="submit", value="Update")
```

This is my app.js file which is starting point of my application:

```
var express = require('express')
, routes = require('./routes')
, user = require('./routes/user')
, http = require('http')
, path = require('path')
, EmployeeProvider = require('./employeeprovider').EmployeeProvider
, myDate=require('date-utils');

  var restify = require('restify');
  var restServer = restify.createServer({ name: 'my-api' });

var app = express();
app.configure(function(){
app.set('port', 3333);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('view options', {layout: false});
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});
app.configure('development', function(){
app.use(express.errorHandler());
});
var employeeProvider= new EmployeeProvider('localhost', 27017);

  //Routes of express jade
  //update an employee Feedback
app.get('/employee/:id/edit', function(req, res) {
employeeProvider.findById(req.param('_id'), function(error, employee) {
  res.render('employee_edit',
           { 
                   //employee: employee,
                    empId: req.param('_id'),
                    com: req.param('com'),
                    titl: req.param('titl'),
                    nam: req.param('nam')

            });
    });
});

 //save updated employee Feedback
 app.post('/employee/:id/edit', function(req, res) {
    employeeProvider.update(req.param('_id').toString(),{
            title: req.param('title'),
            name: req.param('name'),
            comment: req.param('comment'),
            created_at: new Date()
    }, function(error, docs) {
            res.redirect('/')
    });
  });

 app.listen(3333);
```

I have written employeeprovider.js for mongodb connection:

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db;
var Connection = require('mongodb').Connection;
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;
var BSON = require('mongodb').BSON;
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

EmployeeProvider = function(host, port) {
this.db= new Db('node-mongo-employee', new Server(host, port, {safe: false}
{auto_reconnect: true}, {}));
this.db.open(function(){});
};


EmployeeProvider.prototype.getCollection= function(callback) {
this.db.collection('employees', function(error, employee_collection) {
 if( error ) callback(error);
 else callback(null, employee_collection);
 });
};

EmployeeProvider.prototype.update = function(employeeId, employees, callback) {
this.getCollection(function(error, employee_collection) {
console.log('now in update'+employeeId);
   if( error ) callback(error);
  else {
    employee_collection.update(
                                    {_id: employee_collection.db.bson_serializer.ObjectID.createFromHexString(employeeId)},
                                    employees,
                                    function(error, employees) {
                                            if(error) callback(error);
                                            else callback(null, employees)       
                                    });
   }
   });
 };
exports.EmployeeProvider = EmployeeProvider;
```

now by clicking edit button on index.jade it should open employee_edit.jade for editing employee. but it showing the error. address comes in address bar is:

```
http://localhost:3333/employee/:id/edit?_id=5215ad336ad5d6780d000001&com=dfsa&titl=Suggestion&nam=Abhishek
```

It works if i remove 8th and 9th line of app.js

```
var restify = require('restify');
var restServer = restify.createServer({ name: 'my-api' });
```

but i want to use restify in my app, what can i do???
thanx..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling I found that, for all intents and purposes restify 
and express can't coexist in the same node process, because for 
unfortunate reasons, they both try to overwrite the prototype of the 
http request/response API, and you end up with unpredictable behavior 
of which one has done what.  We can safely use the restify *client* 
in an express app, but not two servers. so the "restServer" (declared in 8th and 9th line of app.js) can not be created in this app because we are having an express server which is listening on port 3333.